# formulated cell set back to zero

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning everybody

i have an cell "B6" where it has go the formulas to get the total counts however below code i would like to set the same back to zero without erasing the formulas code in the same cell

i am currently getting an error

```
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Object


 With Sheets("2022")
    Set rng = .Range("B11:AF33", "B6")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "ar" Then

    rng.cell("B6").Value = 0
            'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "i am currently getting an error" what error are you getting?

Comment: `rng.cell("B6").Value = 0` will remove the formula; maybe you want am im-Excel formula, rather than VBA for this?  In B6, you can do something like `If(Counifs( B11:AF33,"ar")>0, 0, formulaInTheCell)`.

Comment: Hi Cyril sorry i already have the formula in B6 cell so and how do i add your suggestion. currently it is =D9*B9*B9 which it give me the total count

Comment: `=If(Countifs( B11:AF33,"ar")>0, 0, D9*B9*B9)` is the recommendation.  You use an if-statement to determine if you use the formula or set the output to `0`.

Comment: Hi Cyril many thanks it worked however how do i start the count again once it has been reset, below it is the formulas but it is stuck =IF(COUNTIF(B11:AF33,"ar")<>0,1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B11:AF33)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B11:AF33,"S",""))))

Comment: Going to fill my comment in as an Answer so we can close this question.  As for "once it has been reset... it is stuck", are you referring to starting the calculation again?  That should be automatic, otherwise you can press `Shift+F9` to calculate on the sheet.

Comment: Hi Cyril yes how do I start calculating the letter S again once it is reset thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding comment as Answer to support closing the question:

`=If(Countifs( B11:AF33,"ar")>0, 0, D9*B9*B9)` is the recommendation. You use an if-statement to determine if you use the formula or set the output to `0`.